# The solutions of a linear differential equation!

Tags: complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

### I can't see how if a differential equation is linear then if it attains a complex solution, then the complex conjugate of the solution is a solution also?
Thanks is advance.

Modification: the linear differential equation has to be real too (from the comments).

Comment: This is not necessarily true. It is if the differential equation is in the form $f'(x)=A(x)f(x)+b(x)$ with $A:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R^{n\times n}$ and $b:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R^n$ (as opposed to $\Bbb C^{n\times n}$ and $\Bbb C^n$ respectively).

Comment: @Gae.S. Would you give some example  to see?

Comment: $y'(x)=i$. Then $ix$ is a solution, but $-ix$ isn't (the ambiental assumption is that the functions are $\Bbb R\to\Bbb C$).

Comment: Or, $y(x)=\cos x+i\sin x$ solves $y'(x)=iy(x)$, but its conjugate function $\cos x-i\sin x$ doesn't.

Comment: @Gae.S. So if the linear differential is real, it will work?

Comment: That is the interpretation as content of my sentence.

Comment: Let $V$ be a real vector space. If $T: V \to \mathbb{C}$ is an $\mathbb{R}$-linear map, it extends to a unique $\mathbb{C}$-linear map $V \otimes \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$. The kernel of this map is $(\ker T) \otimes \mathbb{C}$ and so in particular is closed under complex conjugation.

Apply this to the particular case that $V$ is smooth real-valued functions and $T$ is the linear differential operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have said, this is only true if your coefficients are real, e.g. $y’ = iy$ won’t have this property. So suppose your equation is of the form
$$\sum_{k = 0}^n A_k(x) y^{(k)} = 0 ,$$
and $y$ is a solution. First, I claim that $(\overline{y}) ‘ = \overline{(y’)}$. This should be straightforward to check by breaking $y$ into real and imaginary parts. By induction, this means $(\overline{y})^{(k)} = \overline{(y^{(k)})}$. Thus
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k = 0}^n A_k(x) (\overline{y})^{(k)} & = \sum_{k = 0}^n A_k(x) \overline{ (y^{(k)}) } \\
& = \sum_{k = 0}^n \overline{A_k(x)} \overline{ (y^{(k)}) } \\
& = \sum_{k = 0}^n \overline{ A_k(x) (y^{(k)}) } \\
& =  \overline{ \sum_{k = 0}^n A_k(x) (y^{(k)}) } \\
& = \overline{0} \\
& = 0.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean this (I will do for case 2):

Let $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$,
$$y''+ay'+by=0$$
and the characteristic polynomial is $r^2+ar+b=0$, if $\alpha+i\beta$, with $\beta\neq 0$ is a soluction of the characteristic polynomial, then by the parity of complex solutions we have that $\alpha-i\beta$ it is also. Thus, $\{e^a\cos\beta, e^a\sin\beta\}$ is a basis of the $\mathbb{C}-$vector space of the solutions of the differential equation and therefore any linear combination is also a solution

Comment: I don't get what is "the parity of complex solutions". Please clarify in simple steps.

Comment: Let $P(x)=a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+\dots+a_nx^n$, $a_j\in\mathbb{R}$. If $z\in\mathbb{C}$ is a solution, $P(z)=0$, then $$P(\bar{z})=a_0+a_1\bar{z}+a_2\bar{z}^2+\dots+a_n\bar{z}^n=\overline{a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+\dots+a_nx^n}=\overline{P(z)}=0,$$ thus $\bar{z}$ also is a solution.